# Register highlighting for gedit

Tags: 16.04, gedit

I was messing in CSS and found that gedit doesn't highlight 'opacity' or 'transition' properties.
I also installed an external library and would like to add some highlighting to make it clear where I'm using it.
Is this possible? 
(+please tell me if there's a better way to phrase this question)

Example:
file `style.css`:

```
div.examplediv{
  some more code
  opacity:0.5; /*opacity not highlighted*/
}
```

Comment: can you give an example sample code?

Comment: @Anwar okay ive added an example. also things like ^PIXI.xyz.render^ and stuff dont highlight at all which is annoying. this is why i recently switched to atom but would like to see if anyone has a solution to this still